# Why is COM interop preferred over P/Invoke in .NET?

Tags: .net, com, interop, pinvoke

In our project we are reusing lot's of Delphi code through COM in our asp.net application.

Like this: legacy delphi dll => delphi COM wrapper => .Net interop => asp.net (mvc)

We have some issues regarding access violations, unloading of dll's, etc... I have now ported some to use the legacy dll directly through P/Invoke code.

When I look at resources regarding COM and P/Invoke, people almost always advice to use COM. Why is that? Doesn't P/Invoke have the following benefits:

- checked out code will always use the correct dll‘s instead of the last registered COM
- Multiple versions can run side by side on the servers (for instance: DEV, TEST and QA)
- No more COM registrations hassle
- Much faster than COM communication (articles I read indicate a 30% speed increase)

Comment: can you p/invoke into a 32 bit dll from a 64 bit process? I don't think so.

Comment: Could you give some references that suggest COM is preferred to P/Invoke? I'd very much agree with you that P/Invoke is the better solution where available. Most of the internals in the .NET BCL is implemented in terms of P/Invoke to the Win32 APIs. Only reason to use COM interop is where you have no choice, e.g. interop with Office applications, or Windows API parts that are COM-only.

Comment: Remember DLL hell? Instead of using the correct dll, your code will use the first available dll with the same name. Any API changes will not be detected until runtime, which means that versioning is all but impossible. You can't create a DLL that will serve both older and newer clients without changing the names of the functions themselves

Comment: I dare say, simply because COM is a more natural fit for .NET's OO nature; P/Invoke OTOH is procedural. But use whatever suits you more!

Comment: You can't call a 32-bit dll in-process via COM from a 64-bit process either. Cross-process you could use .NET remoting or WCF as similar to DCOM. This doesn't seem to relate to the the COM vs. P/Invoke choice.

Comment: @Govert: regarding reference, I saw these responses to posts here on StackOverflow while researching how to P/Invoke the delphi signatures.

Comment: @Govert:you're absolutely right currently we run everything x86 for COM interop. Otherwise you'll get a "Bad Image Format exception". Yes we found out the hard way :)

Comment: @stakx: probably also because Visual studio generates a lot of the wiring up, which we now have to code ourselves (.tt to the rescue :) ), but I was wondering if there where any other reasons.

Comment: By using registration-free COM (also known as side-by-side registration) you can avoid item 2 and 3 in your list of drawbacks. Well, item 3 morphs into how to get registration-free COM to do what you want. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx

Comment: @MartinLiversage: thanks I'll relook into manifests. Thanks for the link. I tried it before following this guide: http://www.devx.com/vb/Article/32888/1954

Comment: I don't prefer COM. It's not thread-safe and it's slow, it requires administrative rights to install the COM-component plus it's totally unportable to other operating systems. All in all, I very much prefer to compile my dll to x32 and x64, and call the proper one, with the complete path to it, which totally eliminates dll-hell.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

PInvoke is a very nice tool, but it certainly is no substitute for COM.  PInvoke only supports simple functions with a C syntax; COM lets you implement an object model.  Take the classes in the `Microsoft.Office.Interop` namespaces for example - they are all pure COM classes with no wrappers.  Doing Office interop with PInvoke would be excruciatingly painful.

Another core problem with PInvoke is that it is typically the burden of the client programmer - the person least likely to get them right - to write the declarations.  A COM author can publish an auto-generated type library, much like metadata in a .NET assembly, drastically eliminating the odds for mistakes and no work needed by the client programmer beyond Project > Add Reference.

Addressing your bullets:

- checked out code will always use the correct DLLs instead of the last registered COM
  You are still subject to the vagaries of Windows finding the proper DLL.  The only good way to avoid accidents is to store the DLL in the same directory as the EXE, which is quite possible in COM as well; all you have to do is create an empty file with the name `yourapp.exe.local`
- Multiple versions can run side by side on the servers (for instance: DEV, TEST and QA)
  Not a problem in COM either, using the above technique or by using a reg-free manifest.
- No more COM registrations hassle
  Use a reg-free manifest so no registration is required.  Very simple to do - just set the `Isolated` property of the reference to `True`.
- Much faster than COM communication (articles I read indicate a 30% speed increase)
  It is much *slower* than COM.  You can incur an extra cost by making late-bound COM calls through `IDispatch`; that's roughly as expensive as using Reflection to make the call.

---

There's a third way to do native code interop: writing a managed class wrapper in the C++/CLI language.  The technique heavily used in the .NET framework, particularly in mscorlib.dll, System.Data and PresentationFramework, assemblies that have strong dependencies on native code.  Not, however, very suitable for Delphi; it works best for native code that can easily be called from C or C++.

Comment: Great answer. I tried a reg-free manifest, but couldn't get it to work, at least not from within Visual studio (isolated property). I am not sure how "yourapp.exe.local" changes the behavior of finding the correct COM?

Comment: I don't know how to answer "it doesn't work" questions.  The .local file simply tells the Windows loader to only look in the directory that contains the EXE, regardless of the path specified in the registry key.  Crude and no substitute for a manifest, but it certainly can be handy.

Comment: " 'it doesn't work'-questions." I understand. I'll have to look more into manifest files. I don't think the .local would be a solution in an asp.net environment. The exe in this case would be the IIS worker process, if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: Great comments. But reg-free COM can be pretty tricky, and a terrible example of how to make COM 'easier'. Your first point about the declarations is valid, but could be addressed by the library author providing the P/Invoke signatures, or even making a .NET-friendly object wrapper. And I have to disagree completely with your performance comment. P/Invoke performance is nowhere near IDispatch late-binding. In fact per-call performance of P/Invoke, C++/CLI and (non-IDispatch) COM are all very similar. The CLR + JIT is pretty clever about all of these.

Comment: @Cohen: The last time I had problems getting reg-free COM to work, I made a throw-away VB6 project and then ran Make My Manifest on it.

Comment: Also easy to generate one with Visual Studio, set the Isolated property to true.